# How to make Xamarin Android App onResume to previous screen?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigationbar

When I press the 'Home Button'  it will put the app in background (paused, as expected), then when I open the app again it will open with the **Main Screen**  instead of the **Previous Screen**.
This also affects the 'Back Button' creating a stack of multiple **Main Screen**.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend reading about [Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html/) as there are many different use cases. You are most likely interested in `android:launchMode` here as there are four different modes that will work in your `Intent`.

[android:launchMode documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

There is a great demonstration on the Google play store for this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novoda.demos.activitylaunchmode&hl=en

If anything, you will want to tag the `Activity` with `singleInstance`:

> Same as "singleTask", except that the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task.